# Merge cells in a 1x12 table vertically into blocks of three

Tags: vba, merge, ms-word

I have a table in MS word.
It is 1 cell wide by 12 cells down, each containing a number.
I want to use VBA to merge the 12 cells into 4 cells containing 3 numbers.

So if the 12 cells each contain the numbers 1 to 12, I want to end up with 4 cells.
Cell 1 contains 1 2 3
Cell 2 contains 4 5 6
Cell 3 contains 7 8 9
Cell 4 contains 10 11 12

I've asked ChatGPT to write the code, and after correcting its errors, I have this:

```
Sub MergeCellsVertically()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Set tbl to the first table in the document
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
    ' Loop through each row in the table
    For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count 'Step 3
        ' Check if there are at least three rows remaining
        If i + 2 <= tbl.Rows.Count Then
            ' Merge the cells in the first column
            tbl.Cell(i, 1).Merge tbl.Cell(i + 1, 1)
            tbl.Cell(i, 1).Merge tbl.Cell(i + 2, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

But this gives me 3 cells containing 4 numbers:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12.
I've tried playing with the parameters in the code but I can't get it to merge the 12 into 4 blocks of 3, only 3 blocks of 4. I'm obviously missing something obvious, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the edited version

```
Sub MergeCellsVertically()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Set tbl to the first table in the document
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
    ' Loop through each row in the table
    For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count 'Step 3
        ' Check if there are at least three rows remaining
        If i + 2 <= tbl.Rows.Count Then
            ' Merge the cells in the first column
            tbl.Cell(i, 1).Merge tbl.Cell(i + 2, 1)   
            'tbl.Cell(i, 1).Merge tbl.Cell(i + 1, 1)  'removed from code
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- After each merge, the total number of rows in the table changes. Some cells's row index is changed too.
- The code does not validate whether the total number of rows in the table is a multiple of 3; please add validation code if necessary.

```
Sub MergeCellsVertically1()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Const MERGE_CELL_CNT = 3 ' cells cnt in a merged cell
    ' Set tbl to the first table in the document
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    ' Loop through each row in the table
    For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count / MERGE_CELL_CNT
        For j = 1 To MERGE_CELL_CNT - 1
            tbl.Cell(iR, 1).Merge tbl.Cell(iR + 1, 1)
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

***OR***

- Use a reverse loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MergeCellsVertically()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iR As Long
    Const MERGE_CELL_CNT = 3
    ' Set tbl to the first table in the document
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    ' Loop through each row in the table
    For i = tbl.Rows.Count To 1 Step MERGE_CELL_CNT * -1
        iR = i
        For j = 1 To MERGE_CELL_CNT - 1
            tbl.Cell(iR, 1).Merge tbl.Cell(iR - 1, 1)
            iR = iR - 1
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```